# Unable to launch application using java web start in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, web

I need to use the java web start and when I try to launch the application from netbeans I get an error of unable to launch the application. however when I try to use the java web start from another website (available for everyone) the java web start works perfectly.

Can some one please maybe tell me why is this happening? Could it be because my application does not have any certifications?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does the error say? Are there any stack trace? What does Java Console show?

Comment: a window sort of a popo up comes up saying 'unable to launch application'